# Show $\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x+y}$ does not exist.

Tags: limits

$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x+y}$

If an = ($\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{a}{n}$) and bn = ($\frac{1}{n}$,$\frac{1}{n^a}$) , $a>0$ , $an,bn$ ->$0$ when $n$->infinity

I calculated $f(an)=0$ and $f(bn)=0$, so i need to find an array $cn$ which converges to $0$ but $f(cn)$ is not equal with $0$

Comment: Are you sure that the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: I also tried to prove that it exists but I can not, because $|\frac{xy}{x+y}-0|$ leads you nowhere, hence $(x.y)$ is from $ RxR$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the function is not defined when $x+y=0$, and to have a limit you must be able to evaluate $f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $0$. [If they specify $f(x,-x)=0$ separately, then this is a different ballgame.]

So the key idea is to take $a_n$ very close to $x+y=0$ and approaching $(0,0)$ so that the numerator is large compared to the denominator. Try
$$a_n = \left(\frac1n,-\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}\right).$$

Comment: Your statement that "to have a limit you must be able to evaluate $f(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ sufficiently close to $0$" is not generally accepted as true. For example, Walter Rudin only requires $x$ to be in the closure of the domain of $f$ to make sense of $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#More_general_subsets for another reference which shares this view.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: Of course, I recognize that to be the case, but ordinarily that's not the definition used in (multivariable) calculus courses. Note that I addressed the more general notion, anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x+y}$. $f(1/n,0)=0$ and $f(1/n,-1/n+e^{-n})=\frac{1/n(-1/n+e^{-n})}{e^{-n}}=\frac{-1/n+e^{-n}}{ne^{-n}}=\frac{n-e^n}{n^2}\rightarrow -\infty.$ Hence the limit doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma_1(t) = (t,0)$, $\sigma_2(t) = (t, \frac{t}{t-1})$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x+y} $, 
if $t \rightarrow 0 $ implies $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ so we have:  $\lim_{t \to 0}$ $f(\sigma_1(t))=0$ and $\lim_{t \to 0}$ $f(\sigma_2(t))=1$.

Therefore,  $\lim_{t \to 0}$ $f(\sigma_1(t)) \neq \lim_{t \to 0}$ $f(\sigma_2(t))$
 we conclude that the limit does not exist.